# SegmentedControl changes position when run on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UISegmentedControl`, and I'm trying to set the widths of each `segment`. The code below shouldn't change anything, but it does. Here is the code:

`viewDidApear`

```
NSLog(@"%f", self.segment.frame.size.width); // 369

CGFloat segmentWidth = self.segment.frame.size.width;
NSUInteger firstAndLastSegmentWidth = [self.segment widthForSegmentAtIndex:0] + [self.segment widthForSegmentAtIndex:4];

[self.segment setWidth:(segmentWidth - firstAndLastSegmentWidth) / 3 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[self.segment setWidth:(segmentWidth - firstAndLastSegmentWidth) / 3  forSegmentAtIndex:2];
[self.segment setWidth:(segmentWidth - firstAndLastSegmentWidth) / 3 forSegmentAtIndex:3];

// Note: The following code does not do anything:
CGRect viewFrame = self.segment.frame;
viewFrame.origin.x = self.thirdCell.frame.origin.x - 30;
self.segment.frame = viewFrame;

NSLog(@"%f", self.segment.frame.size.width); // 369
```

**Storyboard:**
[image]

**NSLayoutConstraints:**

[image]

**Simulator:**
[image]
[image]

The first image is when the above code is executed. The second image is when the above code is removed.

Notice all the way to the right of the images, when the code is executed, (first image), the width seems to have changed. But when I do an `NSLog` of widths, before and after I set the segments widths, they display the same results.

My question is, how can I get the `segmentedControl` not to change its' appearance when I run the code above?

Comment: Other than the missing gray bar (whatever that is), those two simulator images look identical to me. I also don't understand your question; if you don't want the code to alter the appearance, why are you running the code at all?

Comment: If you zoom up close, you will see that at the second image, the `segmentedControl` is a bit smaller. I have to run that code because I will be adding segments, then changing their sizes. To simplify things, I just posted the simplest code possible, to show what's wrong

Comment: The gray bar is the shadow of the simulator

Comment: The seqments would be naturally equal, as you add or remove segments.  You shouldn't have to adjust widths, unless you intentionally mean to have a very thin "empty" segment at the far left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the width of the segments does change the visible size of the segmented control, but not the actual size of the control. You can see this by dividing by 5 instead of 3 in your code, and you'll see that the control *appears* much smaller, but if you click to the right of the last segment, you will see that it selects it (if you give the control a background color, it extends to the full size of the control as defined by its constraints). As for why the math doesn't work, I think it's because of the separators. If you subtract 1 for each separator (so 4 in your case) you should get the correct size.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGFloat segmentWidth = self.segment.frame.size.width;
    NSUInteger firstAndLastSegmentWidth = [self.segment widthForSegmentAtIndex:0] + [self.segment widthForSegmentAtIndex:4];
    NSInteger sepWidths = self.segment.numberOfSegments - 1;
    [self.segment setWidth:(segmentWidth - firstAndLastSegmentWidth - sepWidths) / 3 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [self.segment setWidth:(segmentWidth - firstAndLastSegmentWidth - sepWidths) / 3  forSegmentAtIndex:2];
    [self.segment setWidth:(segmentWidth - firstAndLastSegmentWidth - sepWidths) / 3 forSegmentAtIndex:3];
}
```